# Difference between accessing values using subscripting and using just valueForKey in NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I have the following line:

```
_driverName.text = [[[responseDictionary valueForKey:@"response" ] valueForKey:@"driverinfo"]valueForKey:@"name"];
```

But I think I can shrink this line by using subscription in this way:

```
_driverName.text = responseDictionary[@"response" ][@"driverinfo"][@"name"];
```

it seems more clean and readable. 
is it possible to apply this syntax without collateral consequences?
thanks in advance

Comment: Don't use `valueForKey:` unless you are specifically using key-value coding. Always use `objectForKey:` to get a normal value from a dictionary.

Comment: Theoretically, if responseDictionary[@"response" ] is not a dictionary, second line would crash, while the first one will return nil or even some value if there is an NSObject subclass instance with specified properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring the misuse of `valueForKey:` (use `objectForKey:`), you should not use either example in your question. Both suffer from being impossible to debug when you run into issues because the data structure isn't what you thought it was.

While it takes more time, it is worth it in the end to split each access into a separate line:

```
NSDictionary *response = responseDictionary[@"response"];
NSDictionary *driverInfo = response[@"driverInfo"];
_driverName.text = driverInfo[@"name"];
```

But using the modern subscript syntax is always easier and less prone to error than using `objectForKey:` and it ensures you don't mistakenly use `valueForKey:`.